# Run multiple threads when other threads not executing?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

Is there a way to make it so I can have *n* threads run a certain function when other threads are not locking other functions?

I want to achieve something like:

```
pthread_t threadID[10];
pthread_mutex_t blocking;
pthread_mutex_init(&blocking, NULL);
pthread_cond_t go;
pthread_cond_init(&go, NULL);

void * function1() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&blocking); // Only one thread at a time!
    // Do some work
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&go);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocking);
}

void * function2() {
    pthread_cond_wait(&go, NULL); // Imagine 5 threads waiting here.
    // Does some work too!
}
```

What I want is basically that *n* threads run function2, when no threads are running in function1.

I do not wish to lock function2 as threads may execute it concurrently without a problem, so I know the `pthread_cond_wait(&go, NULL)` will not work (even the NULL argument is a bit silly). Also, a broadcast will signal all waiting threads, but only one of those threads will make it to the critical code section. I'm aiming to unlock all threads with a signal, and allow all those threads to execute the code.

I know there are ways to do this without going into thread locking mechanisms (like having a variable be modified inside function1 and function2 must check its value before allowing threads to move forward), but I was wondering if there is a way with mutexes and condition variables, not semaphores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy to do. Use a mutex to protect the shared state, a condition variable when you need to wait for shared state to change, and ordinary integer variables to track the shared state.

When a thread enters a region it should:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Check if it is allowed to run the region. While not allowed, block on the condition variable while releasing the mutex.
3. Increment the count of threads in that region.
4. Release the mutex.

When a thread laves a region it should:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Decrement the count of threads in that region.
3. If the change in the count may have allowed a thread to make progress, broadcast the condition variable.
4. Release the mutex.

It's that simple.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you 100%. If I make it so function2 is enveloped in a mutex, even once I broadcast the condition variable to all of those waiting threads, they will enter a race condition and only one will be able to carry out function2. I'm aiming for allowing all threads in function2 to be concurrent, so I don't see how keeping count of the amount of threads in that region would help. Or maybe I'm just missing something from your explanation!

Comment: What race condition are you talking about? What will keep the others from carrying out function 2? Where do you think they would be blocked?

Comment: Also, note that the function is not really "enveloped in a mutex". I simply executes the two algorithms above, one before it starts processing and one after it finishes processing. Both algorithms release the mutex when they are done, so the mutex is not held during processing.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. Leave the main work of the function unprotected, no mutexes, and simply keep count of the threads in and threads out at the beginning and end of the function, protecting those variables with a mutex. I get the feeling this takes away a bit of "concurrency": each thread enters the function, then one by one they are counted, then they do the work in the order they are done being counted. This solution works for me though, so thank you!

Comment: @VDG If the function takes so little time that the cost of synchronization on entering and exiting the function is important, then the entire design is wrong and you should be looping inside the function.